# retrieving unknowns ( line graph )

Tags: objective-c, graph, plot

The application I'm currently working on will provide the ability to take unknown values based on known values from a line graph. Here's the problem. The line graph will not exist theoretically. But the information provided and past data will be used to be able to find that unknown.

For example

`x axis: known`
`y axis: unknown`
`plotted line graph: partially known`

So in actuality we can draw a graph with the x, y axis and plot the line graph with what we actually know. So say our knowns are:

`x axis: 10; y axis: 15; plot: 160 line`

`x axis: 12.7; y axis: 18; plot: 160 line`

`x axis: 15; y axis: 22; plot: 160 line`

so if we drew this, anything between `10-15` we could detect the y axis by straight line up to the 160 line and then accross to the y axis to find the answer. Thus, more inputted information would eventually lead to every possibility between 1-100 to be answerable.

However, my issue is that in the sense of programatical logic I can't think of where to start. For instance, I'll have my known values such as;

`x = 10; plot = 160; therefore y = 15`

And could be said for the other examples, though how can I manipulate them numbers to find unknowns which I would find on the graph with a simple ruler?

So programatically it would look like

`x = 13; plot = 160; therefore y = ?;`

If anyone has much experience with line graphs or at least with the formulae to unknowns it would be great if you could provide me with some starting information or point me in the right direction. As of right now, I have no idea where to start.

edit;

I'm coming to the conclusion that I will have to interpolate between the two y known values for a ratio of x difference?

so for instance, an input of 13 would show as

`input: 13; find closest less-than to that; find closest greater-than to that;`

`returns 12.7 and 15`

`now find a ratio difference between them`

`take their known y values`

`lowest: 18; highest: 22`

`now lerp(double lowest, double highest, double ratio of difference between xs`

Do I appear to be taking the right path?

Comment: Also, if you would like me to provide a line graph that I'm describing to help you decipher my problem, just ask and I'll provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial Interpolation

`y = y0+(y1+y0)*((x-x0)/(x1+x0));`